# process HTML files using hadoop map reduce

Tags: java, html, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a input folder in hdfs which contain thousands of HTML files :

```
/data/htmls/1/(HTML files)
/data/htmls/2/(HTML files)
.
.
/data/htmls/n/(HTML files)
```

I have a java function which takes HTML file as input and parse it, I want to read these HTML files in mapper function and feed them as input to parser function. Because Input files are processed line by line by map function, is there a way to work with HTML file?

Comment: the fact that they are read line-by-line is a feature of the InputFormat that you are using.  You could write your own (or I imagine there are XML input formats already written) that will process a whole HTML file as well

Comment: how big are the inputfiles? If they are small compared to the block size you can look up `NLinesRecordReader` and modify it to read the full html file. I did that ones for something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how well it would work, but the Mahout [XmlInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/ad84344e4055b1e6adff5779339a33fa29e1265d/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.java) is a decent XML reader. You might be able to adapt that to working for HTML.

In the configuration set the following before creating the Job object:

```
conf.set("xmlinput.start", "<tag>");
conf.set("xmlinput.end", "</tag>");
```

Then set the input class by the following after creating a job object:

```
job.setInputFormatClass(XmlInputFormat.class);
```

This will select everything inside of the specified tag as a single input string.

for instance if you select `<html> and </html>` (or `<body> </body>` or any other matched pair of tags) as start and end tags you should get everything inside of that as a single record, passed to the mapper.

Hope this is helpful.